# What is the implementation of accumulator in boost?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

I've just read the guide of boost library in c++. And there is a sentence in the accumulator part:
"*When defining an accumulator_set<>, users specify the features in which they are interested, **and the accumulator_set<> figures out which accumulators would best provide those features**.*"

What is the method of choosing the best accumulator for the specific feature?

Comment: I think the question needs some more guiding to narrow down the scope of an answer. What would go a long way is making the question less about Boost and including small examples of code and what effects that code has, with the question being how to get there. Boost can still be a useful reference for context, and since Boost is open source, there's some expectation of looking through the source code as well.

Comment: I don't understand the question either. The only way I could make sense of it is the one where the answer is "read the code!", but that's hopefully not what you are looking for.